# mySQL - SUM of column

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables

table 1

```
id product
1  P1
2  P2
```

table 2

```
id amount product_t1
1  100    P1
2  200    P1
3  300    P2
4  400    P1
5  500    P2
```

I want my output to be:

```
product totalAmount(sum of amount)
P1      700
P2      800
```

EDIT: Here is my query so far

```
SELECT T1.product, SUM(T2.amount)
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.product = T2.product_t1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have achieved so far?

Comment: sorry, it is there now. i am getting P1 15000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use group by

```
 SELECT T1.product, SUM(T2.amount)
 FROM table1 T1
 INNER JOIN table2 T2
 ON T1.product = T2.product_t1
 GROUP BY product
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using foreign keys you don't even need the **table 1** for the desired result.

```
SELECT
    product_t1 AS product,
    SUM(amount) AS totalAmount
FROM table2
GROUP BY product_t1
```

What you're missing is the `GROUP BY` statement in order to get a separate row for each individual product

Comment: i am using foreign key T1.product = T2.product_t1. T1.product is unique

Comment: SELECT T1.product, SUM(T2.amount)
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.product = T2.product_t1
Gruop by  T1.product

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT T1.product, SUM(T2.amount)
 FROM table1 T1
 INNER JOIN table2 T2
 ON T1.product = T2.product_t1
 GROUP BY product T1.product
```

Use the `GROUP BY` tag . Group by helps to group your result via value of product

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with `GROUP BY` and `AS`

```
 SELECT product_t1 as product, SUM(amount) AS totalAmount FROM table2
 GROUP BY product
```

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

OR add to your code group by

```
 SELECT T1.product, SUM(T2.amount) 
 FROM table1 T1 
 INNER JOIN table2 T2 ONT1.product = T2.product_t1 

 Gruop by T1.product
```